# Using Yii Framework to query the database for a field with datetime type. I need to query by date only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, yii

Im trying to avoid reworking a bunch of code. Keep in mind im using the yii framework. I have a table in mysql database that has one field name datetime is the type is datetime. So it holds something like this.

```
2014-01-31 09:20:00
```

I need to query that table with only the date along to find all records for that date.

```
$date = 2014-01-31
$app = Appointments::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('datetime'=>$date));
```

My problem is that it will not return anything because the time is also included in the datetime record. Is there a way for me to either add a universal time that mysql will read and select anytime or can I do some kind of query that will just ignore the time and just select the dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a condition `datetime BETWEEN '2014-01-31 00:00' AND '2014-01-31 23:59'`. (By the way, consider a better name for that column.)

But you cannot express that with `findAllByAttributes`, you will need something like this:

```
$date = '2014-01-31'; // the date
$start_time = $date . ' 00:00:00';
$end_time = $date . ' 23:59:59';

$apps = Appointments::model()
  ->findAll('datetime BETWEEN :start_time AND :end_time', array(
    ':start_time' => $start_time,
    ':end_time' => $end_time,
  ));
```

---

**Edit**: I see other answers recommending a different approach - asking MySQL to convert its stored value to match your format. *That does not scale!* If you have thousands of records, this does not make a significant difference, but if you get a few orders of magnitude more than that, you'll see nasty delays.

If you just ask MySQL to match a value without converting it like I suggested, you can put an index on this column and get answers very quickly.

If you ask MySQL to convert the stored values, it has to convert *each record in the table* to determine if it's a match. Other databases can put an index on the converted value, but MySQL cannot, therefore each time this query is run, it has to convert each record again...

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = ".........where date_format(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d')={$date}";

$app = Appointments::model()->findAllBySql($sql );
```

Comment: Please add some description